# Запрос к двум таблицам в SphinxQL

Tags: sql, sphinx

Как выполнить запрос вида:

```
SELECT db1.*, db2.val AS VAL FROM db1, db2 WHERE db2.id = db1.val
```

в *SphinxQL*? Сейчас в `sphinx.conf` имеется 2 *index* и 2 *source* для *db1* и *db2*. В каждом выборка такого типа:

```
sql_query = SELECT * FROM db1
```

для второй *db2* — соответсвенно. И в *yii* я делаю запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM db1, db2 WHERE MATCH('{$q}')
```

Для одной таблицы выводит нормально.

А как сделать для двух?

Answer (score 1):

В Sphinx нельзя делать join между индексами. Поэтому ответ — никак.

Answer (score 0):

Можно по одноименным полям base_field_example в двух индексах index_one,index_two указать фильтр
Select one_name,two_name from index_one,index_two where base_field_example=7